# destructuring and returning data found in odd structure from API request

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, next.js

Having a tough time with this one. I've been searching throughout but don't seem to find a similar scenario...

I'm trying to find the **author** of every **collection** that a user has.

I've made this function to pull data from an api, a specific user that in this case is **proton** as seen at the end of the link:

```
function BCAd() {
  const [bcOwner, setBcOwner] = useState<any>();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await fetch(
        'https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts/proton'
      );
      const { data } = await res.json();
      setBcOwner(data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (!bcOwner) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Spinner />
      </div>
    );
  }

  console.log(bcOwner);

  return null;
}

export default BCAd;
```

The thing is that when i consol.log **bcOwner** , **author** is inside of an array(**collection**) which is inside of another array (**0**), which is inside of an object (**collections**)... So I need to go inside **collections** and then inside every **0**, followed by **collection** to get the author (this sentence wasn't needed but I typed it out to make sure I get what I'm doing lol). And I need to do this for 0,1,2... how ever many the user has. Once I have that author, I want to return all those authors and remove the null. What's the simplest way to tackle this ?

edit: Here is the console.log string

```
{
  "collections": [
    {
      "collection": {
        "contract": "atomicassets",
        "collection_name": "312443155351",
        "name": "Campaigns",
        "img": "QmaCxKxtj4vSbVu2HVhSHs2fxYshgLtzmPLCfdPhQvGNSd",
        "author": "campaigns",
        "allow_notify": true,
        "authorized_accounts": [
          "campaigns"
        ],
        "notify_accounts": [],
        "market_fee": 0.01,
        "data": {
          "img": "QmaCxKxtj4vSbVu2HVhSHs2fxYshgLtzmPLCfdPhQvGNSd",
          "name": "Campaigns",
          "description": "Proton Marketing Campaigns 2D NFTs"
        },
        "created_at_time": "1644873445000",
        "created_at_block": "114487854"
      },
      "assets": "6"
    },
    {
      "collection": {
        "contract": "atomicassets",
        "collection_name": "354415534331",
        "name": "Proton Gifts",
        "img": "QmPfnohRCDs2ZGq3ZchKKVDDv4GwzZG2TDuiVrmCDaDHcr",
        "author": "nftsairdrop",
        "allow_notify": true,
        "authorized_accounts": [
          "nftsairdrop"
        ],
        "notify_accounts": [],
        "market_fee": 0.1,
        "data": {
          "img": "QmPfnohRCDs2ZGq3ZchKKVDDv4GwzZG2TDuiVrmCDaDHcr",
          "name": "Proton Gifts",
          "description": "A little gift from me to you in the Protoverse!"
        },
        "created_at_time": "1640415233000",
        "created_at_block": "105572339"
      },
      "assets": "1"
    }
  ],
  "templates": [
    {
      "collection_name": "312443155351",
      "template_id": "74074",
      "assets": "3"
    },
    {
      "collection_name": "312443155351",
      "template_id": "74112",
      "assets": "3"
    },
    {
      "collection_name": "354415534331",
      "template_id": "44708",
      "assets": "1"
    }
  ],
  "assets": "7"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pulls out the authors

```js
const bcOwner = {
  "collections": [
    {
      "collection": {
        "contract": "atomicassets",
        "collection_name": "312443155351",
        "name": "Campaigns",
        "img": "QmaCxKxtj4vSbVu2HVhSHs2fxYshgLtzmPLCfdPhQvGNSd",
        "author": "campaigns",
        "allow_notify": true,
        "authorized_accounts": [
          "campaigns"
        ],
        "notify_accounts": [],
        "market_fee": 0.01,
        "data": {
          "img": "QmaCxKxtj4vSbVu2HVhSHs2fxYshgLtzmPLCfdPhQvGNSd",
          "name": "Campaigns",
          "description": "Proton Marketing Campaigns 2D NFTs"
        },
        "created_at_time": "1644873445000",
        "created_at_block": "114487854"
      },
      "assets": "6"
    },
    {
      "collection": {
        "contract": "atomicassets",
        "collection_name": "354415534331",
        "name": "Proton Gifts",
        "img": "QmPfnohRCDs2ZGq3ZchKKVDDv4GwzZG2TDuiVrmCDaDHcr",
        "author": "nftsairdrop",
        "allow_notify": true,
        "authorized_accounts": [
          "nftsairdrop"
        ],
        "notify_accounts": [],
        "market_fee": 0.1,
        "data": {
          "img": "QmPfnohRCDs2ZGq3ZchKKVDDv4GwzZG2TDuiVrmCDaDHcr",
          "name": "Proton Gifts",
          "description": "A little gift from me to you in the Protoverse!"
        },
        "created_at_time": "1640415233000",
        "created_at_block": "105572339"
      },
      "assets": "1"
    }
  ],
  "templates": [
    {
      "collection_name": "312443155351",
      "template_id": "74074",
      "assets": "3"
    },
    {
      "collection_name": "312443155351",
      "template_id": "74112",
      "assets": "3"
    },
    {
      "collection_name": "354415534331",
      "template_id": "44708",
      "assets": "1"
    }
  ],
  "assets": "7"
}
const authors = bcOwner.collections.map(({collection})=>collection.author)
console.log('authors',authors)
```

Comment: `({collection:{author}}) => author` too works

Comment: Haha. Yup. I was actually sweating destructuring collection vs. spelling it out for clarity.